# Pass generic EquaityComparer with SequenceEqual

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda, linq-expressions

I'm updating the question, to be more clear:

I am trying to build a LINQ expression for filtering records.

Eg:

```
public string Name {get; set;}
public List<string> Score { get; set; }

 public Student(string name, List<string> list=null)
 {
     Name=name;
     Score=list;
 }
```

And I have a list of these students:

```
    List<Student> listStudent = new List<Student>
              { new Student("Jane", new List<string>{"A","B"}),
                new Student("Joe", new List<string>{"B", "C"}),
                new Student("Jack")};
```

Now, I want to get only the students whose scores match a given list:

```
List<string> scoresToCompare=new List<string>{"B", "C"};
var Result= listStudent.Where(x =>x.Score!=null ? scoresToCompare.SequenceEqual(x.Score,  new StringComparer<string>()): false)
```

And my StringComparer to ignore case when comparing:

```
class StringComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        //Ignore case when comparing.
        return x.ToString().Equals(y.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T item)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(item, null)) return 0;

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
        int hashCode = item == null ? 0 : item.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the product.
        return hashCode;
    }

}
```

Now, I will not know the type of the items in the List until runtime, so I am trying to build an expression to achieve the same result.

```
Type typeOfItemInList = listStudent.FirstOrDefault().GetType(); //Not the exact code, but thats how I get the type
```

How do I call the sequenceEqual method, with the stringComparer ?

```
var callSequenceEqualMethodWithComparer= Expression.Call(typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable), "SequenceEqual", new Type[] typeOfItemsInList }, new Expression[] { listToCompare1,  listToCompare2, **stringComparer**});
```

And finally I need to also do an Expression.Condition to check if the x.Score !=null to avoid the null exception by:

```
Expression.Condition(Expression.NotEqual(expressionOfList1, Expression.Constant(null)), Expression.Convert(Expression.Call(callSequenceEqualMethodWithComparer, expressionOfList1, expressionOdList2), typeof(bool)), Expression.Default(typeof(bool)) );
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're doing from those isolated statements using variables that haven't been shown. Please provide a [mcve] with exepected and actual results. (But no, you shouldn't be calling Equals yourself at all - and it's not clear what you expect to be doing in step 2 when you've already passed the comparer in in step 1...)

Comment: Why are you creating an Equality comparer instead of just using SequenceEqual ?

Comment: Because the SequenceEqual is case senstitive. I need the comparison to be case insensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an expression that creates an object by calling [`Expression.New()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352804(v=vs.110).aspx).

To get the type, you can use `typeof(StringComparer<>)` to get the open generic type for `StringComparer<T>` and then call `MakeGenericType()` on it to get the closed type, for example `StringComparer<string>`.

Put together:

```
Expression.New(typeof(StringComparer<>).MakeGenericType(typeOfItemInList))
```

Comment: svick -

Worked like a charm - thanks so much ! I called the SequenceEqual with the string comparer like this:

var callSequenceEqualMethodWithComparer= Expression.Call(typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable), "SequenceEqual", new Type[] typeOfItemsInList }, new Expression[] { listToCompare1,  listToCompare2, Expression.New(typeof(StringComparer<>).MakeGenericType(typeOfItemInList))});

And that works beautifully. I just had to modify the previous code a little bit to call the SequenceEqual method with 3 parameters.

Thanks again.